# ImportError: No module named 'first_app' after adding to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I have created new app `python first_project/manage.py startapp first_app`,
and after this added app to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'first_app']
```

And after `python first_project/manage.py runserver` get error:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fe13745f6a8>
...
ImportError: No module named 'first_app'
```

Why I can not add app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `first_app` directory should be in the same directory as `manage.py`.

Running `python first_project/manage.py` might have created it in the wrong place. Usually, you would switch to the same directory as `manage.py` and then run `python manage.py`.

Comment: Thanks. After I switched to the same directory and created it with `python manage.py startapp first_app` it worked